# Can someone from a non-English speaking country and university apply for universities inside Canada or US without TOEFL or IELTS?

Tags: united-states, canada, immigration, visa, agency

Someone at [OneKeyVisa](https://onekeyvisa.us/) immigration agency told my friend that she can apply for and get accepted to US universities and get her Student Visa without any English test scores and then request some English units instead after being accepted as a student.

Is that true? Any thoughts on the agency itself? Is it a scam or is this real?

Please provide official solid sources in your responses. Thanks.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is off topic. It is not about the law. It is about university policies.

Comment: So you're saying there's no law to regulate universities' policies regarding accepting an international student in the US?

Comment: "here's no law to regulate universities' policies regarding accepting an international student in the US?" Basically. International student visa can't be issued to people with criminal records or immigration violations, but there are not laws regarding academic standards for admission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether or not OneKeyVisda is "legit" is not a legal question. The law as it pertains to visas is. [This](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/retrieveECFR?n=pt22.1.41#sp22.1.41.g) is the applicable regulation. The applicant must be "accepted for attendance for the purpose of pursuing a full course of study" etc, and

> (iii) The alien, unless coming to participate exclusively in an
> English language training program, has sufficient knowledge of the
> English language to undertake the chosen course of study or training.
> If the alien's knowledge of English is inadequate, the consular
> officer may nevertheless find the alien so classifiable if the
> accepting institution offers English language training, and has
> accepted the alien expressly for a full course of study (or part-time
> course of study for Border Commuter Students) in a language with which
> the alien is familiar, or will enroll the alien in a combination of
> courses and English instruction which will constitute a full course of
> study if required

The law does not require specific test scores, it requires sufficient knowledge of English. It is the responsibility of the university to set the standards. If the language of education is English, then knowledge of language may be assumed: or not, depending on university policy. My university had variable standards in that respect over 30 years.